# Alternative to XDP Adobe Livecycle Forms

Tags: javascript, java, forms

Unfortunately Chrome will not support anymore soon (sept 2015) the Adobe Plugin.

As a consequence the application that a work which is using XDP forms via Adobe Livecycle will have to use Firefox for a while and Internet Explorer.

However the trend is that slowly this types of plugins will not be supported anymore so the way of creating forms will be via HTML5 + javascript.

I searched quite a lot to see is there a viable alternative to create online forms, but for now I did not find anything to match what livecycle was offering: a form builder, cross browser compatibility via the plugin + offline forms.

Do you know any existing framework doing similar jobs? (Java mainly but any other technology should be fine.)